# How to publish html in matlabcentral?

Tags: html, matlab, publish

I write formatted code by matlab editor and [publish it as html document by "publish"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/publishing-matlab-code.html), how can this document be displayed in "matlabcentral"? For example, an external link page [like this1](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/50232/versions/9/previews/MachineLearningMadeEasy_FEX/HumanActivity/html/Human_Activity_Learning.html?access_key=#7)， [like this2](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/48006/versions/3/previews/html/fanChart_examples.html?access_key=)

How is this link done? That is, I already have the html file, what if I publish it to matlabcentral for display?

Thank you very much in advance to anyone who can help me, I appreciate it!

Comment: Both those pages are copyright by The Mathworks, the company that owns that website. I presume they were written by employees, not community members.

Comment: [this one？](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/827f20e9-a637-4412-ac1c-f4954c295799/b7a23f6d-ca89-43d2-af10-e20cb30c3587/previews/html/JSON.html#7)
It seems to be written by a third party person

Comment: [another one?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/53983/versions/5/previews/html/ExampleECGBitalino.html)

Comment: They both have the same prefix "https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/***"

Comment: How did you find those? Are they maybe part of FileExchange submissions?

Comment: I searched through the prefix and found a lot of cases like this, maybe FEX provided the submission.

Comment: Here is a FEX submission that only has an output from the Live Editor in it: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/71001-fft-easy-with-live-editor — Maybe that is how you would publish your generated HTML. if that doesn’t work, you can always host a website on GitHub.

Comment: And this FEX submission contains one of the HTML pages you linked: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/99789-json (look under the examples tab).

Comment: I know these links, it seems that it can only be hosted on github at the moment, matlabcentral hosting doesn't seem to work